# ui grid returning rows in the same order they are selected?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Hi am using UIgrid in an `angularjs` project and when I call the method `gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()` to get the selected rows it returns an array with all the rows but in a random order. Ideally I want to get the rows in the same order they were selected (as if `gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows()` is backed by a queue) . Any idea how to achieve this please ?

This link to plunker shows the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/gD4hiEO2vFGXiTlyQCix?p=preview

Comment: post a fiddle with issue,

Comment: i think there is a bug with that version of angular i was using there , if you upgrade the version in the plnkr to latest it will behave as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the queue by yourself. Something like

```
 $scope.gridOnRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
      var selections =gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
      // add sorted
      selections.forEach(function(s){
        if ($scope.mySelections.indexOf(s) === -1) {
          $scope.mySelections.push(s);
        }
      });
      // remove the ones that are not selected (use for to modify collection while iterating)
      for (var i = $scope.mySelections.length; i >0; i--) {
        if (selections.indexOf($scope.mySelections[i]) === -1) {
          $scope.mySelections.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      console.log($scope.mySelections);
      row.entity.firstSelection = false;
      if (row.isSelected) row.entity.firstSelection = (gridApi.selection.getSelectedCount() == 1);
    });
  };
```

Comment: I thought of that but i was trying to understand the behaviour of gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows() why is it so random . that was my plan B :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug with that version of angular I was using there , if you upgrade the version in the plnkr to 1.6.1 it will behave as expected